# Getting Permission Error 13 When trying to use pathlib and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pathlib

I have created a path to a folder that looks like this:

```
  path = pathlib.Path.home() / 'Desktop' / 'Extraction' 
  print(path)
```

The print is to check if the path is correct and As far as I can tell it is correct
The path looks like this:

```
C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Extraction
```

I then use this path variable as part of the pandas ".to_csv()" function to output a csv file that looks like this:

```
output3.to_csv(path, 'example1.csv')
```

output3 is the variable name for the dataframe.

I keep on getting a permission error even though I have tried running the IDE as admin, and double checked the security permissions of the file in question for the ability to modify and write.

The error looks like this:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\Extraction'
```

Comment: Can you use `to_csv()` to write to a file in the same folder, which does not already exist?

Comment: If I use a non pathlib function and write it out manually using to_csv() I can. It is only when using path I get this error and cannot write to a file in the same folder.

For example like this:

output4.to_csv("C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Extraction/example2.csv", na_rep= 'Unknown')

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. Do not edit questions to put "solved" tags in the title or explain an answer in the question. That's not how the Q&A format works. This is **not a discussion forum**.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), `to_csv()` does not accept separated paths the way `output3.to_csv(path, 'example1.csv')` is doing it. What the function is reading it as is "write to path `C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Extraction` with 'example1.csv' as the csv separator" (which is not a csv file which is likely why thats an issue). You can try to join the path and output first such as through `output3.to_csv(os.path.join(path, example1.csv))`.